# Unable to change configuration of Magento2 Store

Tags: magento2

[image: magento 2 Store configuration]
strong text

Hi, It seem write protected.  I am unable to change configuration of magento2 store. Can you please guide me how to enable sidebar settings.

Comment: maybe those config settings are locked: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-set.html

Comment: I just installed this module and found that I am able to change the configuration of the module.